# What type should I use in my POST request for gorest?

Tags: go

I'm very new to Go so please forgive me if this is stupid obvious.

I'm trying to post a form to a REST API written in Go using gorest. I've successfully done this using GET, but I can't get the POST data to parse into a map. Here is my Go code

gotest.go:

```
package main
import (
  "code.google.com/p/gorest"
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  gorest.RegisterService(new(HelloService)) //Register our service                                        
  http.Handle("/",gorest.Handle())
  http.ListenAndServe(":8787",nil)
}

//Service Definition                                                                                      
type HelloService struct {
  gorest.RestService `root:"/api/"`
  save   gorest.EndPoint `method:"POST" path:"/save/" output:"string" postdata:"map[string]string"`
}

func(serv HelloService) Save(PostData map[string]string) {
  fmt.Println(PostData)
}
```

And my awesome html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8787/api/save/">
  key: <input type="text" name="key" /><br />  
  json: <input type="text" name="json" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I would think that would turn my post data into a nice map that I could access. I fill out the form, hit submit, and it returns an error:

`Error Unmarshalling data using application/json. Client sent incompetible data format in entity. (invalid character 'k' looking for beginning of value)`

EDIT: As greggory.hz points out, the program seems to think that the post data is a json. This error is because a json has to start with a brace, bracket or quote.

If `map[string]string` with `string` it prints the following to the bash terminal where I am running this:

`key=arst&json=%7B%27arst%27%3A%27arst%27%7D`

In the go rest documentation the only example of this that I could find is:

```
posted gorest.EndPoint method:"POST" path:"/post/"  postdata:"User" 
func(serv HelloService) Posted(posted User)
```

But my attempts at creating a custom struct have also fails with the same unmarshalling error seen above.

```
type MyStruct struct {
  key,json string
}
```

Can someone please tell me what data type I should be using?

Comment: I'm mostly guessing here because I'm not familiar with gorest specifically, but I believe it's trying to parse the entirety of the POST data as JSON and not just the value associated with json key.

That is, I believe it except ALL the data in the post request to be formatted as JSON.

Comment: More specifically: key=arst&json=%7B%27arst%27%3A%27arst%27%7D is not valid JSON.

Comment: The string `key=arst&json=%7B%27arst%27%3A%27arst%27%7D` looks like a URL variable path. Try unescaping the string (http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryUnescape). That error sounds like it's trying to unmarshall the word "key".

Comment: The unescaped string is `key=arst&json={'arst':'arst'} <nil>`. Can you change `root:"/api/"` to `root:"/api/" consumes:"application/json" produces:"application/json"` in the `gorest.RestService` line? It's what the example on the gorest homepage has. Maybe makes a difference.

Comment: I think this *may* be a bug in gorest, or we're both missing something vital in the docs.. I've just replicated your issue and I've noticed that, even if you leave the form fields blank, it tries to decode it as `application/json`, and you get the same error on the `k` from `key`. Very strange. Will keep digging.

Comment: Thanks, @Intermernet. `url.QueryUnescape` will be useful a few steps from what I posted here. In the mean time I can just assume the `PostData` is a `string` and `url.ParseQuery` by hand. It feels hackish though.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to post an html form to a service expecting a json body. But your browser isn't going to format the post as application/json. It will instead format it as a urlencoded body. The problem isn't in your go server code it's in the html form. You probably want to use javascript to package up and send your post instead of a standard html form.

```
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="endpont" value="http://127.0.0.1:8787/api/save/" />
  key: <input type="text" name="key" /><br /> <!-- this should be used in your post url -->
  json: <input type="text" name="json" /><br /> <!-- this will get sent by your javascript as the post body -->
  <input type="button" onclick="send_using_ajax();" />
</div>
```

Comment: The above is my answer for fixing the code you've written. However /api/save is not a particularly restful endpoint. To fit more with what gorest is going to be expecting you're endpoints will be more like: /api/keyname and GET,POST,PUT and company would be the action you are doing. GET=Retrieve, POST=Modify, and PUT=Create usually.